# Oracle SQL Loader control file to ignore ellipsis

Tags: oracle, position, sql-loader, controlfile

I have an Oracle SQL Loader control file based on position in a text file. One particular field periodically gets an ellipsis `'...'` from the source, which causes a carriage return in the loading table.  No matter how many times I request `'...'` to NOT be used by these users, there is eventually someone who forgets, or due to staff turnover, etc.  Here is the current control file line for that field:

```
TRAN_DESC   POSITION(153 : 202)  Char,
```

Is there any command that can be added to this line in order to ignore special characters such as an ellipsis?

Comment: How does an ellipsis translate to a carriage return? What character sets are involved? And is it an actual ellipsis character, or three periods?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think of `REPLACE`. Here's an example.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, tran_desc varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

Control file:

```
load data
infile *
into table test
(id        position(1:2), 
 tran_desc position(3:12) char "replace(:tran_desc, '...', '')"
)

begindata
10LittleFoot
11Big...foot
```

Loading session and result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test2.ctl log=test2.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Tra 5 17:03:39 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * from test;

        ID TRAN_DESC
---------- ----------
        10 LittleFoot
        11 Bigfoot

SQL>
```